# Partition not resized despite empty space on device

Tags: filesystems, partition, block-device

It seems that the device `/dev/sda` has plenty of space available

```
root@Vanuatu:~# sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL | grep -v loop
NAME   FSTYPE    SIZE MOUNTPOINT                      LABEL
sda             49,5G                                 
├─sda1 vfat      512M /boot/efi                       
├─sda2             1K                                 
└─sda5 ext4      9,5G /                               
sr0    iso9660  58,3M /media/pkaramol/VBox_GAs_6.1.26 VBox_GAs_6.1.26
```

However the partition `/dev/sda5` used for the `root` filesystem, cannot be resized

```
root@Vanuatu:~# resize2fs /dev/sda5
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 2489600 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Why is that? Is there another action that needs to be taken in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The filesystem is already 2489600 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

2,489,600 blocks of 4KiB is 9.5GiB. The file system already uses all the room available in the partition.

You need to resize the partition first, using `parted`, `fdisk` etc.

Comment: Is there an option to resize the root partition without booting from live cd?

Comment: The last time I tried, there wasn’t.